# Embedding Canvas in an iframe?

Tags: iframe, same-origin-policy, canvas-lms

I am trying to embed the canvas webpage in an iframe in my app, but I can't because the `Same-Origin` header is set.

Does anyone know of a workaround/other way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get it working by using Electron's  tag.